# Relative website layout doesn't apply on paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-position, paragraph

I chose the page to be relative, but here I stumbled upon a problem where the container and header's width change when the browser is restored down, but not the paragraph (id="slogan"). Depending on the browser size, the dots after Slogan go past the right border of the container ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFlK3.jpg)).

I would really appreciate your opinions on where I went wrong.
Thanks,

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 #container {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
}
#koke {
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: dotted;
  background-color: #AC9441;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#slogan {
  margin-left: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <header id="koke">
      <p id="slogan">
        Slogan .............................................................................................
      </p>
      <img src="img205.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="120" id="logo" />
    </header>

    <nav id="menu">
      <p>Menu | Menu | Menu</p>

    </nav>

    <main id="main">Content.....</main>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Would something like `#slogan { width: calc(75% - 120px); }` work for you?

Comment: Still no. Maybe does it have to do with the fact that slogan is inside a header, which is inside a container ??

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the CSS:

```
#koke p{
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This will force paragraph text to wrap in that header section

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I wanted it to reduce the size relatively, jut like the container or the header.

Comment: Sorry I looked at your picture and question and thought that's what you wanted. The position:relative CSS tag isn't changing the width of your elements, it's for positioning elements on the page relative to other elements. It's the margin and width:auto CSS that is changing the widths. Infact, I don't think position:relative serves a purpose here.

Comment: I set margin and width to auto, but still got the same result.